# Subclassing UITableViewCell not showing added styles

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard, subclass, subclassing

I am trying to create a subclass of a UITableViewCell with custom styles that my app uses for every cell in its multiple table views. I am building this for iOS 7.1. For some reason setting the style in `initWithStyle` seems to have no effect.

My code:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        [self.textLabel setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        [self.contentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    }
    return self;
}
```

In my storyboard I have set the class of the cell in the `UITableViewController` to `MYSubTableViewCell`. I have the Table View Cell style set to **basic**, I set it to custom too, which had no effect.

In `MyTableViewController.m`:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MYSubTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}
```

I need to have cells with a predefined background and text, is this the right way to go about it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, when your cell is instantiated from a storyboard, the cell is not initialized with `- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier`. It is initialized with `- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder`.

Your initializer will never be called. You should override `initWithCoder:` instead.